# Error: ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vba

```
Run-Time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

Help me to resolve this problem.

I don't know why this happened cause I just followed the instructions.

```
    Sub QueryExcel(ByVal SQL_Statement As String)
    On Error GoTo errHandle
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim sConnection As String, sSQL As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, iCheck As Integer
    Dim num_records As Long
    
    sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                  ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;ReadOnly=False"""
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADOBD.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADOBD.Recordset")
    
    sSQL = UCase(SQL_Statement)
    
    conn.Open sConnection
    
    If Left(sSQL, 6) = "UPDATE" Or InStr(sSQL, "INSERT INTO") > 0 Then
    
        conn.Execute sSQL, num_records
        MsgBox num_records & "records affected.", vbInformation
    Else
    
        rst.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        With ws
            .Move ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
            
            '// Paste Record Set
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
            
            For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, i + 1) = rst.Fields(i).Name
            Next i
            
        End With
    
    End If
     
    Door:
    If rst.State <> 0 Then rst.Close
    If conn.State <> 0 Then conn.Close
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
    errHandle:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbInformation, "JJ Excel SQL.Application"
    GoTo Door
    End Sub
```

Code Above this text

 this Code : `If rst.State <> 0 Then`

 make all of this long code get error

Comment: Just before it hits the `if rst.state` put in your intermediate window `?typename(RST)` I've got a feeling the object RST will be nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look at it, it's probably never loading the rst object properly.

Check your IF ELSE. Statement and I think you will find it never does this command

`rst.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`

You can check by putting a pause just before your error. And then in the intermediate window typing.

`?typename(rst)`

It it returns nothing you know where your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADOBD.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADOBD.Recordset")
```

In the above lines change `ADOBD` to `ADODB`